# display lat long on Google Maps v3 Api

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps-api-3

i have latitude and longitude in my database now i want to display multiple markers on Google maps v3  but the problem is when i am retrieving my value(lat , long) only one marker is displaying on map because its getting last value of loop and other values are overwritten..

My code is this..

```
 <?php foreach($this->searchResult as $result): ?>
 <ul>
 <li><?php echo $result['user_id']; ?>

 <li><?php echo $result['name']; ?></li>
 <li><?php echo $result['Latitude']; ?></li>
 <li><?php echo $result['Longitude']; ?></li>


<li><?php if($result['country'] == '1'){echo "America"; }else{ echo "";} ?></li>
 <a href="<?php echo 
 $this->url(array('controller'=>'search',  'action'=>'get-Details',            'id'=>$result['id']))?>">Details</a> 
</ul>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var berlin = new google.maps.LatLng(40.7144, -74.0061);

  var lat = new Array();
  var lon = new Array();
  var lat = <?php echo $result['Latitude']; ?>;
  var lon = <?php echo $result['Longitude']; ?>;


 var neighborhoods = [

  new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lon)

 ];


 var markers = [];
 var iterator = 0;

 var map;

 function initialize() {
var mapOptions = {
  zoom: 4,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  center: berlin
};


  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvass"),
        mapOptions);
```

}

```
 function drop() {
for (var i = 0; i < neighborhoods.length; i++) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    addMarker();
  }, i * 200);
}
```

}

```
  function addMarker() {
  markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
  position: neighborhoods[iterator],
  map: map,
  draggable: false,
  animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
}));
   iterator++;
}
</script>


<?php endforeach;?>



<?php  echo $this->paginationControl($this->searchResult, 'Sliding', 'pagination.phtml'); ?>

<div id="map_canvass" style="width:800px; height:300px"></div>

<button id="drop" onclick="drop()">Drop Markers</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't create a script-tag in a foreach loop. A better approach is to generate a data object and render it into the script block as JS variable. Then you can loop within JS over this data-object and add the markes.

json_encode is a good way to print data-objects.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

pseudo code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        var neighborhoods = <?php echo json_encode($allHoodsIWantToAdd);?>;
        ...
    }());
</scritp>
```

Comment: actually i just want to store all lat,lon value here.. and then fetch it.. 
but its only retaining the last value.. 

var neighborhoods = [

   new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lon)
 ];

Comment: The equals operator makes an assignment and overwrites the previous assignment. To extend an javascipt-array you can use the push() function. `var neighborhoods = []; neighborhoods.push(firstCoordinate); neighborhoods.push(secondCoordinate);`

Comment: Or assign all elements at the same time. `var neighborhoods = [firstCoordinate, secondCoordinate];`